# Behavioral simulation works but not post synthesis simulation

Tags: vhdl, vivado

My component works perfectly in the behavioral simulation but when I try the post synthesis simulation it does not work at all.
I think that the main issue is that a port is not connected during the synthesis. This port, obviously, must be connected!

Other warnings in the Synthesis are: "Inferring latch", "signal not in sensitivity list"

This is the architecture and signals declaration. I am not sure if the problem is here or somewhere else.

````
    PORT (      
        -- inputs
        i_clk       : IN std_logic;                         
        i_start     : IN std_logic;                         
        i_rst       : IN std_logic;                         
        i_data      : IN std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);      
        --outputs
        o_address   : OUT std_logic_vector(15 DOWNTO 0);    
        o_done      : OUT std_logic;                        
        o_en        : OUT std_logic;                        
        o_we        : OUT std_logic;                        
        o_data      : OUT std_logic_vector (7 DOWNTO 0)     
    );
END myEntity;   


ARCHITECTURE beh OF myEntity IS 

    --*********** CONSTANT ****************
    CONSTANT Nwz    : integer := 8; 
    CONSTANT Dwz    : integer := 4;     

    --*********** signals ****************  
    SIGNAL timer : natural := 0; -- timer dei clock per lettura RAM

    -- component OUTPUT signals
    SIGNAL my_o_done    : std_logic := '0';                                     

    -- component OUTPUT signals for RAM
    SIGNAL my_o_address : std_logic_vector(15 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => 'Z');     
    SIGNAL my_o_we      : std_logic := 'Z';                                     
    -- RAM signals
    SIGNAL my_mem_do   : std_logic_vector (7 DOWNTO 0):= (OTHERS => 'Z');       
    -- FSM signals
    SIGNAL WZ_NUM       : integer range 0 TO 7 := 0;                            
    SIGNAL WZ_OFFSET    : std_logic_vector (3 DOWNTO 0) := (others => '0');     
    SIGNAL ADDR         : std_logic_vector (6 DOWNTO 0) := (others => '0');     
    SIGNAL WZSTART      : std_logic_vector (6 DOWNTO 0) := (others => '0');     
    SIGNAL WZEND        : std_logic_vector (6 DOWNTO 0) := (others => '0');     
    -- FSM states
    SIGNAL PS   : FSM_state := LCK;     -- FSM Present State
    SIGNAL NS   : FSM_state;            -- FSM Next State   

    -- controller SEC signals
    SIGNAL SEC_start :  std_logic_vector (1 TO 4) := "Z000";
    SIGNAL SEC_end   :  std_logic_vector (1 TO 4) := (OTHERS => '0');

    -- secCOMP signals
    SIGNAL cmp_en   :   std_logic := 'Z'; 
    SIGNAL cmp_r1   :   std_logic_vector(6 DOWNTO 0);
    SIGNAL cmp_r2   :   std_logic_vector(6 DOWNTO 0);    
    SIGNAL cmp_done :   std_logic := '0';
    SIGNAL cmp_cc   :   std_logic_vector(1 TO 2);
    -- secADDER signals
    SIGNAL add_en   :   std_logic := 'Z';       
    SIGNAL add_r1   :   std_logic_vector(6 DOWNTO 0);
    SIGNAL add_r2   :   std_logic_vector(6 DOWNTO 0);    
    SIGNAL add_done :   std_logic := '0';
    SIGNAL add_sum  :   std_logic_vector(6 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => 'Z');

    -- secONEHOT signals
    SIGNAL one_en   :   std_logic := 'Z';   
    SIGNAL one_inc  :   std_logic := '0';   
    SIGNAL one_di   :   std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
    SIGNAL one_done :   std_logic;
    SIGNAL one_do   :   std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);```
````

Comment: Evaluating your problem would need the entire entity declaration and architecture body. Latches are inferred when there are execution paths both with and  assignments to signals or variables. A signal not in a sensitivity list addresses a mismatch in simulation and post synthesis hardware. Provide a [mcve] with complete error and warning messages. See User Guide 901 Vivado Design Suite Synthesis, IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 (RTL Synthesis, withdrawn), IEEE Std 1076-2008 16.8.2.4.10 Interpretation of the high-impedance value ('Z'). It appears your code isn't synthesis eligible.

Comment: See [Behavioral simulation works but not post synthesis simulation](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/FPGA-Configuration/Behavioral-simulation-works-but-not-post-synthesis-simulation/m-p/1106314#M17425).

Comment: We had a saying at my previous job: "no errors, no warnings". We said this to encourage less experienced engineers not to ignore warnings. Warning can be serious and should be attended to. Your two warnings - "Inferring latch", "signal not in sensitivity list" - both indicate serious problems with your design. You need to find out what then mean and then fix them. And to answer your question: the problem is somewhere else.